# Is there any framework for rich web clients on top of html/css/js?

Tags: javascript, python, rad, rich-internet-application, rich-client-platform

Some RAD tools like openobject use rich web clients. I.e. their client side code reside inside the browser and they talk to the server via xml-rpc or json-rpc only and change the view accordingly, all the javascript and css are transferred only once. Such rich web clients would increase the productivity in enterprise class web application that have lots of processes and forms etc.

I would like to use such a rich web client inside my own application. I tried to search but found only openerp-web, which is tightly integrated to its server. Is there any other rich web client framework available? if not, is there any design detail I can look into to create my own?

Thanks.

Edit: Browser is a client which uses http and similar protocols to talks to web server which serve pages that the client displays. Rich web client is a client which sits on top of Browser which talks to the server, send data, receive data and information about How to update the view etc and do it. Similar to Vaadin, such rich web client will eliminate any code requirement on client side and and all the coding will be done on server side. Belows are such thin clients.

1. pjax ( jquery )
2. vaadin ( java )
3. openobject web client ( python )
4. nagare ( python )
5. seaside ( smalltalk )
6. p4a ( php )

this are all such clients that once properly setup will allow to code on only on sever and still provide great ajax like experience.

edit 2: I think I found better name for what I want. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_client_platform  rich client platform, but web based.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_AJAX_Platform is the most similar to that. Now I want this in python. I will post link if I port it myself.

edit 3: http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/11/15/modern-web-applications-are-here/ here is related article about similar technology.

Comment: First, please define what exactly makes a "rich web client".

Comment: did you mean ***RAD frameworks for web applications***? (deym i sound like Google)

Comment: There are **many** client frameworks out there. Have you looked at Dojo, or Mootools, or jQuery Mobile, or anything? Honestly this is a job for google.

Comment: I have done my homework I think. I am looking for client side RAD tools that helps me avoid doing any client side coding. Check out the example I have pointed out. All of them allow ajaxifying your app without writing much client side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for future readers,

I ended up using angularjs.org which is very easily extensible over normal html.

Comment: have you looked at http://boilerplatejs.org ? It might not be a RCP, but a reference architecture for building RCP with JS.